# Nhibernate Common columns in base class

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance

I want to design following scenario

Base class (Id, Name, order, Value)

3 Derived classes derive1, derive2, derive3 inheriting properties from base

There is no table for base class. And 1 table for each derived class. 3 tables have same columns.

How can I create mapping file ignoring base class?
Do I need to create 1 mapping file for each derived class? can I achieve this using only 1 mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 mapping files. Check out this reference:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete

Comment: The same link from the NHibernate docs: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete